# Помогите разобраться с отступом в массиве

Tags: python, информатика

**Условие задачи:**

На вход программы поступает последовательность из N натуральных чисел (8 ≤ N ≤ 1000). Необходимо определить количество пар (ai и bj, i < j) элементов таких, что их произведение оканчивается на 1, и между ними находится не менее 4 чисел.

**Описание входных и выходных данных**

В первой строке входных данных задается количество чисел N. В каждой из последующих N строк записано одно натуральное число, не превосходящее 10000. В качестве ответа программа долж-на вывести одно число, количество пар элементов, удовлетворяющих условию.

**Пример входных данных:**

10

12

81

2

7

33

99

21

11

121

10

**Пример выходных данных для приведенного выше примера входных данных:**

3

**Моя реализация на python:**

```
n = int(input())
count = 0
arr = []

for i in range(n):
    arr.append(int(input()))
    
for i in range(0, n - 4):
    for j in range(0, i + 4):
        if (arr[i] * arr[j]) % 10 == 1:
            count += 1
print(count)
```

**Вопрос:**

В условии задачи написано, что расстояние должно быть не менее чем 4, в циклах я указывал `n - 4` и `n + 4` соответственно, но почему-то программа выдёт результат 4 а не 3 как должно быть. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Правый предел range - 1 => попробуй n - 5 и n+5 соответственно

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет так:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 4, n):
        if (arr[i] * arr[j]) % 10 == 1:
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо вашего

```
for i in range(0, n - 4):
    for j in range(0, i + 4):
```

примените

```
for i in range(0, n - 5):
    for j in range(i + 5, n):
```

---

Результат для значений в вашем примере

> ```
> 3
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

> ...между ними находится не менее 4 чисел

значит, что отступов должно быт по меньшей мере **5**, и

> ... (a<sub>i</sub> и b<sub>j</sub>, i < j) ...

вместе с предыдущим ограничением значит, что внутренний цикл (для `j`) нужен начинаться не с `0`, а с `i + 5`.

Comment: не совсем понял, почему для того, чтобы соблюсти отступ в 4 нужно прописывать 5 а не 4. Можете объяснять чуть подробней?

Comment: Да, могу. Сколько чисел между `0` и `5`? Четыре: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`. Что должно добавить к числу `0`, чтобы между `0` и результатом были 4 числа? Ответ: `5`.